# "requestFeature() before adding content" Using DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to create a simple login prompt using a DialogFragment. Im getting the good old requestFeature()-exception. I've spent the better half of this day googling around and trying different solutions with no succes. So I turn to you. Here is the stack trace:

```
12-16 22:15:59.986  24137-24137/se.elsgard.zombiehorror E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{se.elsgard.zombiehorror/se.elsgard.zombiehorror.MapsActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:320)
        at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:253)
        at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:337)
        at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:362)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:266)
        at android.app.DialogFragment.onStart(DialogFragment.java:492)
        at android.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1723)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:931)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1075)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:1865)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5388)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And here is the activity showing the dialog:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LoginFragment.NoticeDialogListener{

private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
private LocationManager locationManager;
private LocationListener locationListener;
private Marker you;
private ServerListener serverListener;


private LatLng position;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    position = new LatLng(59.2542, 15.2467);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    serverListener = new ServerListener(this);
    serverListener.start();

    showLoginDialog();

    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if(you != null)
                you.remove();

            position = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            you = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position).title("You"));
            you.showInfoWindow();
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(position));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    };
}

private void showLoginDialog(){
    DialogFragment newFragment = new LoginFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "Login");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    try{
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

private void setUpMap() {
    //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position).title("You"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, 15));
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

}

@Override
public void onDialogLoginClick(Dialog dialog) {
   EditText usernameEditText = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.nameEditText);
   EditText passwordEditText = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText);
   String username = usernameEditText.getText().toString();
   String password = passwordEditText.getText().toString();
   serverListener.send("LOGIN " + username + " " + password);
}

@Override
public void  onDialogRegisterClick(Dialog dialog) {
    EditText usernameEditText = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.nameEditText);
    EditText passwordEditText = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText);
    String username = usernameEditText.getText().toString();
    String password = passwordEditText.getText().toString();
    serverListener.send("REGISTER " + username + " " + password);
}
}
```

And the DialogFragment:

```
public class LoginFragment extends DialogFragment {
private EditText usernameEditText, passwordEditText;

private View view;
public interface NoticeDialogListener {
    public void onDialogLoginClick(Dialog dialog);

    public void onDialogRegisterClick(Dialog dialog);
}

private NoticeDialogListener mListener;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    builder.setView(view);

    builder.setPositiveButton("Login", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            mListener.onDialogLoginClick(LoginFragment.this.getDialog());
        }
    })
            .setNegativeButton("Register", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    mListener.onDialogRegisterClick(LoginFragment.this.getDialog());
                    //LoginFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
                }
            });
    Dialog dialog = builder.create();
    //dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    return dialog;
}


public LoginFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
    usernameEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.nameEditText);
    passwordEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText);
    return view;
}


@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (NoticeDialogListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}
}
```

Comment: Call `super.onCreate()` first, then `requestFeature()`

Answer (score 0):

If you go from this:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

to that:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

It should work

Comment: Yes. This is one of the things I've read on thousands of forum posts by now and I've tried them all. So just let us break it down:
1. In what class should I call them? The MapsActivity or the LoginFragment?
2. In either of these,  requestWindowFeature cannot be resolved, so I guess I should use getDialog.requestWin...
3. In what member function should I call it? If I call it in onCreate, it will throw a NullPoiterException since the dialog has not yet been instantiated..

Comment: Welk the Error appears in your MapsActivities onCreate Method, and the solution should be to exchachang the first and second line in this method like shown above... If you do this you get an error anyway? I will need this error message too, to define class, method, and solution

Comment: After you changed this, also exchange the third line in this onCreate Method with the second one

Comment: So it should go first super.onCreate... Then setContentView... And then requestWindowFeature... In this Direktion

Comment: Okay, I tried the different variants. With super.onCreate, requestWindowFeature and setContentView and I get the same. java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{se.elsgard.zombiehorror/se.elsgard.zombiehorror.MapsActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content

And with super.onCreate, setContentView and requestWindowFeature and I get the exact same error, but it is this time caused by MapsActivity.java:40, which is the requestWindowFeature call. I can't post the full stacktrace in a comment..